# Repairing fstab (read only /)

Tags: linux, debian

I had a typo in my fstab and it boots to a commandline but is readonly, I know what the error is but i can't change it because it's mounted as readonly. I want to mount the filesystem and make the changes. I know I can boot a live distro and edit it that way, but i was wondering if there was an easier way to do it.

It's debian lenny by the way.

Comment: You're probably in single user mode.  Remount the file system.  Do a "man mount" and lookup the "remount" and "rw" options.

Comment: Yeah, well, I disagree with closing sysadmin questions, but not enough to get into a re-opening war with people.

Comment: Get a live disk and boot the distribution on the cdrom.  Then mount "/" as something like "/media/cdrom" and edit the entries.

Comment: as long as its linux its fine with me ;)

Comment: If you want your question to stay open you'd better ask what geeky baby name to choose while fixing an fstab.

Answer (score 40):

Yes, if you end up in single-user mode with a readonly root, try:

```
mount / -o remount,rw
```

Maybe a -n is necessary, maybe not. That should remount the root fs read/write (assuming there's nothing wrong with it).

Comment: Doesn't help, keeps saying it's a read-only file system since fstab is wrong. troyane's answer did it for me.

Answer (score 24):

I know that question is outdated, but saw it, because nowadays got in the same trouble.
I broke my `fstab` manually (make a typo in parameter).

That was very easy to correct `fstab` from readonly mode. We must mount `/` in read-write mode.

If `/etc/fstab` is correct, you can simply type:

```
mount -n -o remount /
```

But if `/etc/fstab` is wrong (as it was in my case), you must give the device name and possibly the type, too: e.g.

```
mount -n -o remount -t extX /dev/hdaX /
```

Where `extX` is your filesystem type and `/dev/hdaX` -- is partition you use for your root mount point.

To see all your available partitions just type `ls /dev/[sh]d*`.

Comment: `remount,rw` does not work with typo in fstab as it tries to use also options from there and fails on them. But using `mount -n /dev/vg0/root / -w -o remount` worked and I had a RW filesystem, where I could fix fstab.

Comment: Comment from @Marki555 worked for me on Centos 8 with wrong fstab. Actual command: `mount -n /dev/mapper/vg_vgname-root / -w -o remount` (just do `ls /dev/mapper` if you are not sure about volume group name), then I could edit `vi /etc/fstab` and `reboot`

Comment: additional info:  for finding out name and type, read this article: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/linux-restoring-deletedoverwritten-etcfstab-file-what-kwiatkowski/

Answer (score 7):

```
#mount -n -o remount,rw /
```

if /dev/sda1 is the real device, then do:

```
#mount -n -o remount,rw /dev/sda1 /
```

Answer (score 2):

@troyane saved my hassle by providing

```
mount -n -o remount -t extX /dev/hdaX /
```

I was on Orangepi3 EMMC when I had a typo in UUID of root having ext4 filesystem.

The command remounted in read-write mode and I fixed my fstab

```
mount -n -o remount -t ext4 /dev/mmcblk2p1 /
```

Answer (score 0):

My kernel command line looks like this:

```
$ cat /proc/cmdline
root=/dev/sda4 ro
$
```

Tell grub that it should omit passing `"ro"` to the kernel when booting (pressing `esc`, `e` on the entry you want edit will allow you to edit the arguments given to the kernel), and it will mount your root file system not read only anymore. Then you can change your */etc/fstab* and restart.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, in grub2 after pressing "e" I have changed "ro" to "rw init=/bin/bash" then the root filesystem is mounted read and write so I could change the content of /etc/fstab file.

Answer (score -3):

If you have something wrong with your /etc/fstab file. Please follow the following steps.

1. boot your ubuntu system or restart your computer
2. since you can not start your system, you will encounter some errors like

“a start job is running for dev-disk-by....
(you may need pressing F2 key to come the linux command terminal to see this)

3. use command vi /etc/fstab and edit your fstab file
4. use # to commend out some problems and add something you want put in the fstab file.
5. finish editing. hit shift+z and save the modification
6. use command reboot to restart your system
7. it works again

Please comment here, if you have questions